# Fast computation of the partition function modulo a prime

Tags: partitions

[Rademacher’s formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) for the partition function allows fast computation using high precision arithmetic, but requiring a lot of memory.  [Here](https://fredrikj.net/blog/2014/03/new-partition-function-record) is an example computation of $p(10^{20})$ by Fredrik Johansson.

**Question:** Is there a $p$-adic or modular analogue that allows fast computation modulo an arbitrary small prime, with low memory (related only to the size of the prime)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no known method to compute $p(n)$ modulo a small prime using less than $n^{1/2+o(1)}$ time or memory, except for those cases where a Ramanujan-like congruence applies.

Comment: Hi, could you share how to compute it in $O(n^{1/2+o(1)})$?

Comment: Using the Rademacher series; see the links in the question.

Comment: Though https://fredrikj.net/math/hrr.html has a lot more details. :)